# Resize window size C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

Is it possible to resize a running application's window size from within another application?
I want that when the application that I am building starts, another application (let's say itunes)'s width be reduced to its 2/3 so that the remaining 1/3 be occupied by my application. The two application should be running altogether and accessible by the user.
Please help if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `SetWindowPos` to resize another process's window.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, 
        int x, int y, int width, int height, uint uFlags);

    private const uint SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

    private void resizeItunes()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] itunesProcesses = 
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("iTunes");

        if (itunesProcesses.Length > 0)
        {
            SetWindowPos(itunesProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle, this.Handle,
                0, 0, Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width * 2 / 3,
                Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height, SHOWWINDOW);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help me getting started

Comment: This is definitely the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the Windows' handle so use the `FindWindow` function at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx then pass the handle to the window using `SendMessage`.

You need to `SendMessage` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950.aspx or `PostMessage` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944(VS.85).aspx with WM_SIZE (0x0005) and specify the size.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to read these references and implement the solution