# C# Trying to scale another applications window

Tags: c#, resize, parent-child, scaling

So I have a WFP project and I used `SetParent()` to make a separate application a child of my project. The only issue is I can not get it to scale to the size I want. SetWindowPos doesnt seem to be doing much of anything that I can tell. Is there another way to go about it.

Also the child application is not resizable on its own so that could be part of the problem. I dont even necessarily need to resize it as much as scale it down. Any ideas or directions would be awesome, TY.

I did try what was listed here but no luck.
[Resize window size C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004256/resize-window-size-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Apperently my handle changed when I called SetParent() on the process. Using FindWindowEX() and finding the window handle again and everything works now when calling SetWindowPos().